# auto scroll to menu when clicking button

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

I have card div with a button. when I click this button it should dropdown a menu. I want to make auto scroll to menu view when clicking this button, but I want to achieve that only on mobile phone not on desktop. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried window.scrollTo()?